# Regarding Tier0 switch to downstream servers connectivity

Tags: network, sdn, vpc

I have been reading up on the connectivity patterns of tier0 switch to the downstream servers in a cloud environment(e.g. AWS, Google clouds), however, I am curious to understand why none of the cloud providers use technologies like vPC (virtual port channel etc.) to provide enough redundancy between the server and it's upstream switch.

On one hand, vendors advertise their technology with huge impact on customer business,on the other hand I see technology giants (say AWS, Google cloud)avoiding usage of their technologies.
What could be the primary reason to avoid usage of such technologies ?

Is it due to 
 the following points that come to my mind:

1. Technologies like vPC won't scale when we have huge number of servers to connect to upstream network devices as in case of AWS.
2. There are lots of bugs in vendor proprietary technologies like vPC that may lead to extremely huge dependency on the vendor, which cloud providers tend to avoid as they want to be autonomous and rely on home grown technologies ?

Please correct my understanding if I am wrong and educate me by throwing some light on my points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it’s mostly a cost and scaling  issue. When operating in the scale those big networks operate, you don’t care about a single server losing connectivity, you think in scale of data centers going offline. Why invest in more switch ports to increase availability of one single server when you can load balance that traffic over tens of thousands of servers worldwide.

Comment: Obligatory [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1737/)